# Software that skips pauses in lecture recordings

Tags: online-learning, learning, lecture-notes

I enjoy listening to lectures at 1.5x speed because I retain the same amount of information while saving time. I find that 2x speed is usually too fast *except* when the speaker pauses. I'm curious if there is a video playback software that plays at 1.5x speed, *and* skips pauses at 2x speed. A pause could be any stop (or substantial decrease) in audio for 1-2 seconds while the same image is displayed on screen.

Comment: There were algorithms written to stop/start recording around adverts.... But why not just edit your source files once then they are ready...

Comment: This should probably be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ since it is not specific to academia.  Please read their [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before posting, though.